# ¿Cómo puedo conectar los niveles de mi videojuego al menú del mismo?

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy buscando conectar de alguna manera los niveles de mi videojuego con el menú principal pero no sé cómo hacerlo. Desearía saber si existe alguna forma sencilla de hacerlo.

La idea es que pueda seleccionar un nivel desde el menú principal y, una vez seleccionado, que me lleve hasta ese nivel y pueda comenzar a jugar. No estoy seguro de si tengo que añadir el código del nivel al código del menú, o no sé de qué otra forma. Aquí está el código del menú:

```
import pygame
import button

pygame.init()

#Crea la ventana del menu
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Menu principal")

#Variables del juego
game_paused = False
menu_state = "main"

#Define las fuentes
font = pygame.font.SysFont("arialblack", 40)

#Define los colores
TEXT_COL = (255, 255, 255)

#Carga las imagenes de los botones
resume_img = pygame.image.load("images/button_resume.png").convert_alpha()
options_img = pygame.image.load("images/button_options.png").convert_alpha()
quit_img = pygame.image.load("images/button_quit.png").convert_alpha()
video_img = pygame.image.load('images/button_video.png').convert_alpha()
audio_img = pygame.image.load('images/button_audio.png').convert_alpha()
keys_img = pygame.image.load('images/button_keys.png').convert_alpha()
back_img = pygame.image.load('images/button_back.png').convert_alpha()

#Crea las instancias de los botones
resume_button = button.Button(304, 125, resume_img, 1)
options_button = button.Button(297, 250, options_img, 1)
quit_button = button.Button(336, 375, quit_img, 1)
video_button = button.Button(226, 75, video_img, 1)
audio_button = button.Button(225, 200, audio_img, 1)
keys_button = button.Button(246, 325, keys_img, 1)
back_button = button.Button(332, 450, back_img, 1)

def draw_text(text, font, text_col, x, y):
  img = font.render(text, True, text_col)
  screen.blit(img, (x, y))

bg_image=pygame.image.load("images/fondo_menu.png").convert()
#Loop del juego
run = True
while run:
  screen.blit(bg_image,[0,0])
  #Revisa si el juego está pausado
  if game_paused == True:
    #Revisa el estado del menu
    if menu_state == "main":
      #Dibuja boton de pausa
      if resume_button.draw(screen):
        game_paused = False
      if options_button.draw(screen):
        menu_state = "options"
      if quit_button.draw(screen):
        run = False
    #Verifica si el menu de opciones está abierto
    if menu_state == "options":
      #Dibuja diferentes botones de opcion
      if video_button.draw(screen):
        print("Video Settings")
      if audio_button.draw(screen):
        print("Audio Settings")
      if keys_button.draw(screen):
        print("Change Key Bindings")
      if back_button.draw(screen):
        menu_state = "main"
  else:
    draw_text("Presiona ESPACIO para empezar", font, TEXT_COL, 170, 310)

  #Gestor de eventos
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        game_paused = True
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      run = False

  pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Postularía que cada nivel es un ejecutable separado. Eso reduce el problema a hacer un pgma menú que ofrezca los niveles y luego lance el ejecutable correspondiente. Dividir para reinar.

Comment: Beneficio adicional: simplificas el desarrollo. En lugar de un sólo gran programa, tienes *ene* programas pequeños.

Comment: Hola, gracias por su respuesta. Cada nivel está pensado para hacerse individualmente como un ejecutable así como menciona =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo diría que, primero, tengas cada nivel separado en varios modulos. Similar a lo que dice Candid Moe en los comentarios, pero en lugar de ejecutables separados, los niveles son módulos de Python, haciendo que no sea necesario recurrir a ejecutar otros programas.

Después, yendo a tu pregunta, podés usar un enfoque en programación orientada a objetos. El plan sería crear una clase Window, que almacenará todo lo relevante para trabajar con la ventana.

```
class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()

        self.surface = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        self.view = Menu(self)


        self.run = True

    def mainloop(self):
        while self.run:
            self.surface.fill((0, 0, 0))

            view = self.view

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if(event.type == pygame.QUIT):
                    self.run = False
                else:
                    view.process_event(self, event)
            
            view.process(self)
            pygame.display.flip()

            self.clock.tick(60)

        pygame.quit()

window = Window()
window.mainloop()
```

Obviamente, este código está incompleto, ya que falta definir el objeto Menu.

El plan es guardar en el atributo view un objeto. La clase Window se encargará de, dentro del loop que hicimos, llamar a los diversos métodos del objeto view actual (con "actual" me refiero al view que está establecido cuando comienza a procesarse el fotograma).
Como por ejemplo, process para dibujar y actualizar el juego y process_event para procesar cada evento recibido.

Lo especial de esto, es que podemos cambiar el atributo view por un objeto que tenga los métodos process y process_event y, entonces, el código encargado de controlar el juego va a ser completamente distinto.

Entonces, ahora agreguemos la clase Menu y Game:

```
class Menu:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("arialblack", 40)

    def process_event(self, window, event):
        if(event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
            if(event.key == pygame.K_SPACE):
                window.view = Game(self)
    
    def process(self, window):
        window.surface.blit(self.font.render("espacio para empezar", 0, (255, 255, 255)), (0, 0))

class Game:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.player = pygame.Surface((40, 40))
        self.player.fill((200, 100, 0))
        self.playerx = 0
        self.playery = 0

    def process_event(self, window, event):
        pass

    def process(self, window):
        left_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()[ord("d")]

        if(left_pressed):
            self.playerx += 1
        
        window.surface.blit(self.player, (self.playerx, self.playery))
```

En el init de la clase, cargamos lo necesario. En el caso de Menu, cargamos la fuente. En process, nos encargamos de dibujar y actualizar el juego, y en process_event, establecemos el atributo view una instancia de la clase que controla un simple "juego".

---

**Notas**

- El "juego" es simplemente mover un jugador a la derecha y nada más. Esto es por que el juego es en realidad puramente ilustrativo y en realidad se usa para demostrar como funciona este enfoque.
- El juego podría optimizarse y hacerse más dedicado, pero decidí que eso no era relevante para la respuesta, por lo que hice solo lo necesario del juego para mostrar un ejemplo de este enfoque.

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, pero aún no logro entender muy bien el tema de POO, estoy algo confundido, podrías implementar lo que mencionas en mi código actual del menú? Se lo agradezco mucho, en serio!

Comment: Quizá te alcance un tutorial para entenderlo: https://kinsta.com/es/blog/programacion-orientada-objetos-python Sin embargo, aunque me gustaria que en vez de copiar mi estilo aprendas por tu cuenta, haré lo que me pides. Para eso necesito poder ejecutar el código y hacer pruebas con el. Por lo que mi duda es, importas el módulo "button". De donde viene ese módulo?

Comment: Oh, me olvide de decirlo. De nada, un placer c: